# TAniIndicator bug?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

When I use the component TAniIndicator in my app for Android, the Indicator sometimes (most of) show two indicators, one is the Android version, the other is a Windows version. This is a bug or I'm just forgeting to check something in the inspector?

A image to illustrate:

[image]

This is the code that I use to create the indicator in runtime:

```
aiEmpresa := TAniIndicator.Create(vsEmpresa);
aiEmpresa.Parent := vsEmpresa;
aiEmpresa.Align := TAlignLayout.Center;
aiEmpresa.Visible := true;
aiEmpresa.Enabled := true;
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue in action.

Comment: I edited the question with the code that I use to create the Indicator.

Comment: The other is not a Windows version indicator, that is the iOS indicator, also you are probably leaking memory with your creation of this object if you are not clearing all the references

Comment: I use `aiEmpresa.DisposeOf` when I finish load the stuff. Is this enough?
Also, if I use `DisposeOf` on `vsEmpresa` the `aiEmpresa` is cleaned from memory too, right?

Comment: I would rather (I my opinion) instead of using `DisposeOf`, work with objects as they where intended to under ARC, meaning remove all the references to the Object and have ARC work as intended, Instead of creating your component with a owner and then setting a parent aswell, if its not needed create it with a owner don't (meaning nil) but still give it a parent, now when you want to free the object just assign the parent to `nil`, and your object will be freed, to me this is much better than the crude `DisposeOf` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem with this command: `aiEmpresa.StyleLookup := 'aniindicatorstyle';`